# Create a setup file for my project with SQL Server LocalDB database- c# vs2017?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, localdb

I am having trouble with creating a setup file for my project in VS2017. I developed a Windows Forms application with C# and it uses a SQL Server LocalDB database.

So far and with the help of a tutorial, I installed Visual Studio Installer project and I created an empty setup project. In the application folder i added  my `project.exe` and my `database.mdf` then hit build.

It generated my setup file and I installed it, the application works but when I try to open the database i am getting an error that says :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Program Files\NomadSysteme\GTC_Setup\db_alarme.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share

I believe it has something to do with my connection string which this is :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="GTC_Frater_Razes.Properties.Settings.db_alarmeConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db_alarme.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Is there something that should be installed in the target machine?

I am stuck at this problem for a week now so if someone can help me out that would be great.

Comment: If you want to use a SQL Server LocalDB database - then you **must install** the LocalDB bits on the target machine

Comment: @marc_s, i don't know what it is !!! could you be more specific please?

Comment: and how can install it with my setup? i'm using visual studio installer .

Comment: See [this good blog post](https://www.sqlshack.com/install-microsoft-sql-server-express-localdb/) that explains all the necessary steps

Comment: @marc_s, i used Advanced installer and found a package named sql server express localDB and i said to myself it must be it, i added to the setup and it worked perfectly. that was the information i was missing, thank you so much .